# Disable SSLv3 in Wildfly app server

Tags: ssl, wildfly-8

How to disable SSLv3 in Wildfly app server. Following configuration

```
<server-identities>
    <ssl protocol="TLSv1">
        <keystore path="https.keystore" relative-to="keystore.home" keystore-password="secret" alias="https" key-password="secret" />
    </ssl>
</server-identities>
```

falls back to SSLv3, if SSLv3 requested. Looks like associated bug https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1153853 in redhat is closed as "WONTFIX"

Comment: If that's their attitude they will need to change it. This is a major requirement since the discovery of the POODLE SSLv3 vulnerability. Did you try what it says [here](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1232233)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add [enabled-protocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"] to  element. It works with Wildfly 8.2

Comment: Hello I just tried your solution, however it's not obvious to me how to add the mentioned protocols to the element. I tried this: <ssl protocol="TLSv1" enabled-protocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2">...</ssl>. When I startup the host I get an error: "JBAS014788: Unexpected attribute 'enabled-protocols' encountered" I guess the attribute needs to be added elsewhere, but where?

Comment: Nevermind. The protocolas have to be added within the domain.xml within the https-listener like this: *<https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="SSLRealm" enabled-protocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"/>*